# Magento order observer not catching the order

Tags: magento, observers

I can't get the magento to respond to event sales_order_save_after. I use observer for the event. I am pretty sure my xml is well formed, since I use Magicento for this. This is my config.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <config>     
        <modules>         
            <Magicento_Modul>             
                <version>0.1.0</version>         
            </Magicento_Modul>     
        </modules>     
        <global>         
        <models>             
                <magicento_modul>
                    <class>Magicento_Modul_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>magicento_modul_resource</resourceModel>
        </magicento_modul>             
        <magicento_modul_resource>
            <class>Magicento_Modul_Model_Resource</class>
            </magicento_modul_resource>
        </models>         
        <blocks>
            <magicento_modul>
                <class>Magicento_Modul_Block</class>
            </magicento_modul>        
        </blocks>         
        <helpers> 
            <magicento_modul> 
                <class>Magicento_Modul_Helper</class>
            </magicento_modul>         
        </helpers>          
        <events>            
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers> 
                    <magicento_modul_model_observer>
                        <class>Magicento_Modul_Model_Observer</class>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <method>act</method>
                    </magicento_modul_model_observer>
                </observers>              
            </sales_order_save_after>  
        </events>       
        </global>
 </config>
```

and this is my act method inside local/Magicento/Modul/Model/Observer.php:

```
class Magicento_Modul_Model_Observer { 
     public function act($observer)     { 
    $order=$observer->getPayment()->getOrder();

    $sa=$order->getShippingAddress();

    $fp = fopen('fajl_iz_magicento_modula.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $sa);            

     }  
 }
```

Comment: Try to use <sales_order_place_after> instead of <sales_order_save_after>. Else try to dispatch an Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have problem on act method of your observer. The event sales_order_save_after do not dispatch the payment object, but order. So make correction in your act method like:

```
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()
```

Instead of

```
$order=$observer->getPayment()->getOrder();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that was helpful. I ended up using anothere event anyway: sales_order_payment_place_end